# Using a static template constexpr with SFINAE fails

Tags: c++, sfinae

I'm trying to create a class template which provides a way to check if the template was given a specific type.

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T, typename U>
class Acceptor
{
public:

    template<typename X>
    static constexpr bool accepts =
        std::is_same<T, typename std::remove_reference<X>::type>::value ||
        std::is_same<U, typename std::remove_reference<X>::type>::value;

    void set(T value) { /* some code */ }
    void set(U value) { /* some code */ }
};
```

I would like to use the template above in a SFINAE expression as follows:

```
#include <type_traits>

class Setter
{
public:
    template<typename T, typename U,
        typename std::enable_if< T::accepts<U> >::type * = nullptr>
    void set(T instance, U&& value)
    {
        instance.set(std::forward<U>(value));
    }

    template<typename T, typename U,
        typename std::enable_if< !T::accepts<U> >::type * = nullptr>
    void set(T instance, U&& value)
    {
        // Nothing to do here
    }
};
```

but the code doesn't compile in GCC 7.1.0 or MSVC for VS2017. The former is giving me the following error:

> error: 'struct std::enable_if<(T:: accepts < )>' is not a valid type for a template non-type parameter

but I can't see the reason.

Comment: you probably forgot to use template keyword before `accepts`. Try: `T::template accepts<U>` in your condition

Comment: Can you even template member variables?  That's new to me.

Comment: @HenriMenke as long they are static... why not?

Comment: @W.F. thank you, that was the reason, now it's compiling.